# populate gridview in asp through c# getting record info from xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm trying to get the selected record to appear in a gridview, but the selected record is in an XML file, which is populating the dropdown box - the dropdown box is the selector for the record i want to display in the gridview, I've got a good start on it, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to show the full record. It's probably something small, but I've searched and googled for the last 6 hrs.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            loaddropdown();
        }
    }

    private void loaddropdown()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml("http://localhost:63707/registrations.xml");
        DropDownList1.DataSource = ds;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "id";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "id";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
}
```

---

xml record is

```
   <registrations>
  <Registration>
     <id>1</id>
     <fullName>Keiran Bernal</fullName>
     <emailAddress>k.bernal@gmail.com</emailAddress>
     <registrationType>conference only</registrationType>
     <attendingSocialEvent>1</attendingSocialEvent>
  </Registration>
  <Registration>
     <id>2</id>
     <fullName>Cordelia Pierce</fullName>
     <emailAddress>c.pierce@outlook.com</emailAddress>
     <registrationType>conference and workshops</registrationType>
     <attendingSocialEvent>0</attendingSocialEvent>
  </Registration>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like creating a datatable and then binding to the datatable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication78
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("fullname", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("email", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("registrationType", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("attending", typeof(string));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach(XElement registration in doc.Descendants("Registration"))
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add( new object[] {
                    (string)registration.Element("id"),
                    (string)registration.Element("fullName"),
                    (string)registration.Element("emailAddress"),
                    (string)registration.Element("registrationType"),
                    (string)registration.Element("attendingSocialEvent")
                });


            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks heaps for the reply, really easy to follow. my only question is - what do you mean binding to the datatable? completely confused me at that point

Comment: The control to the table.  Binding is same thing as using DataSource.

Comment: ah okie dokie, I've gotten it mostly working, but any time it populates the gridview, it has column errors. ive got gvRecord.DataSource=dt.Select("id="+id);

id is the dropdownbox.selectedindex.tostring();

i figured that would grab the ID from the datatable row, and then match it.

Comment: If you are using DataSource then just specify dt and not any columns.   The error may be due to the coluimns in the view being assigned other than strings.

Comment: yeah, ive set it to just dt, and it populates the entire gridview, not just 1 particular row that i request. with the Select() method, it returns, RowError, RowState "Added" and HasErrors as null.

Comment: Is the null the last row of the view where a user can add new data?